# View showing hex instead of text

Tags: mysql, select, hex, view

I am making a view to display information about faults logged against asset ids (These are just IDs for things within the company that could break).

The assets have an ID(INT 4) and a description(VARCHAR 150) assigned to them.

I have another table that is used when logging a fault which stores asset_id (INT 4).

I join these tables together by doing

```
select * from faults left join assets on faults.asset_id = assets.id
```

I am also doing a case statement to decide how to show the description.

```
  CASE
      WHEN faults.asset_id = assets.id
      THEN
         assets.description
      WHEN faults.asset_id IS NOT NULL AND assets.id IS NULL
      THEN
         CONCAT('Invalid Asset ID - ', faults.asset_id)
      ELSE
         'No Asset ID assigned'
   END
      AS asset_desc
```

When I run this query I get results fine.

However, when I turn the `select` statement into a `view`, I get some strange values returned in the `asset_desc` column.

Eg:

`496e76616c6964204173736574204944202d20313233`

`496e76616c6964204173736574204944202d20313234`

I've been looking into this for a while and I can see this is actually hexadecimal. I'm not sure why it is converting into this, or how to fix it.

Any/All help is much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the concatenation was causing this error, if I remove the `CONCAT('Invalid Asset ID - ', faults.asset_id)` and replace with `'Invalid Asset ID'` then it works. I'll just have to live with it being like that...